# Center data displayed in an XRLabel in DevExpress

Tags: devexpress, xtrareport

I have a DevExpress XtraReport where I want a field with text to be displayed in the middle of the row regardless of size.

The data is bound to an XRLabel but it will not align to the center of the label.

I have tried setting it via TextAlign and also via style and setting the stylepriority to true for text align but it still is not aligning to the center.

I am referring to the label with the "FinalNotices.PracticeName" in the picture below.

Thanks

[image: DevExpress report]

Comment: What is the result you get?

Comment: Its left justified.  So it shows in the center in the design interface but is left justified when run

Comment: Have you checked your code? Do you change any properties there?

Comment: No properties set in the code

Comment: Add a breakpoint to BeforePrint and AfterPrint events for this label and check the value of 
TextAligment property there.

Comment: What seems to be hapening is that the Style set on the control is being completely ignored.  Is there a setting somewhere that disables styles in a report?

Comment: So I rebuilt the report, reconnected the fields- and it workd perfectly...  No changes other than it has been rebuilt,